# Dialog animation fillAfter doesn't work

Tags: android, xml, dialog, android-animation

I can't manage to get the fillAfter property of an animation to work.
I used it both in the translate and the set of the animation in xml but it always jumps to the standard dialog position at the end. Is this even possible?

Current slide in animation in xml:

```
<set
android:fillAfter="true"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="70%"
    android:fromYDelta="100%"
    android:toYDelta="70%"
    android:duration="2000" />

</set>
```

The Themes.xml that is being applied to the dialogs:

```
<style name="theme_dialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/style_slide_in_dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="style_slide_in_dialog">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/animation_slide_in_dialog</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/animation_slide_out_dialog</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Did you find an XML based solution to this? If so please consider updating this post.

Answer (score 0):

Animations like `TranslateAnimation` are temporary. If you want the effect to persist when the animation is complete, you need to register an `AnimationListener` and do something to make the change permanent in `onAnimationEnd()`. For example, with a `TranslateAnimation`, you would need to adjust your `LayoutParams` to have it reside in your final position.

Comment: This is not correct. Animations are supposed to remain if you utilise the Animation:setFillAfter method or the XML android:fillAfter attribute.

Comment: @RichieHH: First, this is referring to a technique that is fairly obsolete, unless you're still supporting `minSdkVersion` of less than 11. Second, `fillAfter` only makes the animation *appear* to reside in the final position. It controls only where pixels are drawn, not where touch input needs to come from. That's fairly useless in most cases; hence, you need to do something to make the animation permanent when done.